# JPanel forgets its position

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JPanel that should be positioned.  I tried to use setBounds in the panels constructor, but it didn't work. It seems like the bounds are forgotten when I call paintComponent.

```
public class Panel extends JPanel {

    public Panel() {

        setBounds(120,100,20,300);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Prints out (0,0)
        System.out.println("Location: " + getLocation());
        g.drawOval(0,0, 60, 60);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swing the positioning of a component is rarely determined by the component itself. It is usually determined by the [LayoutManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) of the container (which is affected, in turn, from its own container's layout manager).

The rationale is that visual positioning is not a "divide and conquer" type of activity: The positioning of one component affects the positioning of the other components, so you need some sort of a "central positioning authority", AKA: the layout manager.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use absolute positioning (nothing I would recommend except in very rare cases) you have to remove the parents' layout manager by calling `setLayout(null);` on the parent container:

```
getContentPane().setLayout(null);
getContentPane().add(new Panel());
```